# Is it possible to use continue in conditional operator? in c language

Tags: c

I am going to print `no` if for loop `i` is not divided by 3 and otherwise continue the loop

```
(i%3==0)? continue : (printf("no"));
```

am getting error on this line

Comment: No it's not possible, because `continue` is not an expression, and all parts of a conditional operator must also be expressions. Use an if statement.

Comment: No.   Both the possible results of a `?:` operator must be expressions, that yield compatable types.  This, among other things, ensures that `x = a ? b : c`  makes sense.    `continue` is not an expression.    If you want to use `continue`, the use an `if` (e.g.  `if (i%3 == 0) continue; else printf("no");`   (preferably with blocks delimited by `{}`)

Comment: The only way to do it would be to use a language extension, such as `gcc`'s statement expressions.  I would advise against it though, since it's completely unnecessary and the result code would be non-portable (i.e., it's not C).  Just use an ordinary `if` statement for the `continue`, and fall through to the `printf` otherwise.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Is your goal to make the biggest possible mess out of cleanly structured code? I would highly recommend not to use such code. A ternary operator is not the same as an `if` and should not be used as one.

Comment: No this won't work for the reasons given in earlier comments.  This is also just plain bad style - the `?:` operator is not a replacement for an `if-else` statement, and shouldn't be used as one.

Comment: It seems you don't know the usage of `? .. : ..` construction. What if you write `if (i%3== 0) continue; else printf...` - maybe it is longer?

Answer (score 3):

No. In a ternary operator, both of the values must be expressions. `continue` is a statement, not an expression. Use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can do it with while loop easily :

```
while(1){

if(i%3 == 0)
    i = i % 3;
}else{
    printf_s("no");
    break;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not specify exactly what they want to accomplish with the loop, but my guess is that `i` should be a counter variable. So my guess is that it should rather be `for (int i = 0; i < SOMEVALUE; i++ )` instead of `while (1)`. However, because the OP did not provide details, there is little point in trying to solve OP's overall task. Instead, it only makes sense to address OP's immediate problem, which is the line with the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

This will **not** work as the conditional operator is part of an *expression* whose value is either the second or third clause, and `continue` is a *statement*.

The conditional operator can be used in ways such as this:

```
days_in_february = is_leap_year() ? 29 : 28;
```

So now imagine if what you wanted was allowed.  If you did this:

```
val = (i%3==0)? continue : (printf("no"));
```

Then what would `value` be set to if the condition was true? `continue` is not an expression and therefore doesn't "have a value" so such a statement wouldn't make sense.

You need to use a standard `if` statement to accomplish this:

```
if (i%3==0) {
    continue;
} else {
    printf("no");
}
```